# How to find flows that access Browser Session IDs?

Tags: visual-workflow, session-id, summer-23

In the upcoming Summer'23 release, this is one of the updates: "Disable Access to Browser Session IDs in Flows". The "Review Your Flows" section of the update simply states: "Remove any dependencies on the $Api.Session_ID variable and test your flows."

So how do I do this? If it was Apex, I could simply search in Visual Studio Code. If it was a custom field, I could ask where it was being used.

But how do I search for uses of browser session ids in flows, except by manually opening all flows and inspecting all elements?

Comment: Surely if you extract the flow metadata in the usual way to your local file system you can use your IDE to search for this string in the flow metadata?

Comment: @PhilW "extract the flow metadata in the usual way". I have never done that, so it is not so usual for me. But I will look up on how to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the elaborated answer, with thanks to PhilW for his comment that is the foundation of it.

First, create a `package.xml` file with the following contents:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```

Next, start the [Developer Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php)

Go to Migration > Retrieve

Select the `package.xml` file you have just created, select Single Package and click Next. Click Retrieve. Wait until finished and then Download ZIP File.

The ZIP file contains one file per flow. These are XML files, which you can examine using your favorite tool/editor.

Comment: Alternatively if you are using [sfdx CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm) and [enable source tracking on your org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm), you can just `sfdx force:source:pull` and get all the metadata off your org.

Comment: Honestly you should be doing this to ensure you have backups of the metadata on your org, even if you don't use it for development of your metadata.